# Accessing a JSON object inside another JSON object

Tags: android, json

Here is part of the json file I am using (from YQL).

```
{
"query":{
  "count":1,
  "created":"2014-08-03T11:11:01Z",
  "lang":"en-US",
  "results":{
     "quote":{
        "symbol":"GOOGL",
        "Ask":"575.00",
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Here is the code I tried to use to parse:

```
           // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonStringUrl);

            // get the array of users
            JSONObject query = json.getJSONObject("query");
            JSONObject results = query.getJSONObject("results");
            JSONObject quote  = results.getJSONObject("quote");

            String ask = quote.getString("ask");
            Log.e(TAG, "Ask: " + ask);
```

This doesn't work (as I assumed it wouldn't) but I am not really sure how I would go about changing it. Thanks for taking the time to read/answer this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code looks fine to me other than that you've requested the value for the key `"ask"`, and the key in the JSON is `"Ask"` (capital `A`). (Capitalization matters in JSON.)

Comment: Ok now I feel silly, it works now :D thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BenSmith: :-) We've all done it. The question has to be: Why would they use all lower case for everything else, but a capital for that one key?